# If a nonzero element $[a]$ of $Z_n$ is a zero divisor, can there be two distinct nonzero elements $[b]$ & $[c]$ st. $[a][b]=0$ & $[a][c]=[0]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I believe the answer is that there is only one distinct $[b]$. I kept trying to solve the problem through computation.

$[a][b]=[0]$

$[a][b][c]=[0][c]$

$[0][c]=[0]$

I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction because that last line doesn't tell me what $[c]$ is.

Comment: There can be many such (consider for example when $n$ is a power of $2$ and $a=2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$. Then, $[4][2]=[8]=[0]$ and $[4][4]=[16]=[0]$.